# Not able to update polyline geometry via update cursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am trying to read polyline from the feature class and then add a point to the geometry and the update it in the same feature class....
I am able to read it and add the new point...but not able to save  the geometry?

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(near_features, ["objectid","SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        lnObjid= row[0]
        array = arcpy.Array()
        geom = row[1]
        for part in geom:
            for pnt in part:
                array.append(pnt)
        for ptid,lineid,ptX,ptY in zip(lst_pt_objIds,lst_Ln_objIds,lst_Pt_X,lst_Pt_Y):  
            if lineid == lnObjid:
                new_point = arcpy.Point(ptX,ptY)
                new_array = arcpy.Array([array.getObject(x) for x in range(1,array.count)]+[new_point])
                array = new_array  
        if array.count !=0:
            geom = arcpy.Polyline(array)
            cursor.updateRow([row[0],geom])   
            array.removeAll()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
geom = arcpy.Polyline(array)
```

with

```
geom = arcpy.Polyline(array, spatial_reference)
```